# Non Clustered Index on UniqueIdentifier columns

Tags: sql, azure, database-performance, non-clustered-index

WE have a simple SQL query selecting two columns like below

```
SELECT TEAMID,iSvALID FROM teams where teamid='{{guid}}' and subid = {{guid}}.
```

we had issues with performance of this query as there was no index which I also have added now... like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20170725-191322] ON [dbo].[TableName]
    (
        [subid ] ASC,
        [TeamId] ASC,
        [Date] ASC
    )
INCLUDE ([IsVAlid])
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

The problem now is that it takes a few Milliseconds sometimes to execute the query but a few seconds!!! some times .

And because of some constraints we can't change the type of GUID column and also we get this from an exernal system.

Is there a way we can still make sure performance will be good

Comment: Is anything else happening on the server when it takes a few seconds?  Perhaps the issue is simply cold-cache versus warm-cache.

Comment: I wouldn't expect such variation in performance and I would expect the performance to be good given that your index covers the columns in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, By the way this SQL query i called is used by and API and  I have enabled App Insights and that the API call is taking 6ms sometimes and 6-8 secs some time